# NameError: name 'lines' is not defined

Tags: python

I wrote a python program and trying to debug it but I can't get rid of following error message. What am i doing wrong ? I will appreciate your help.

Problem seems to be lines but I have already declared lines as an array.

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-bf5f54aacfbf> in <module>()
     16  csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
     17  for line in csvreader:
---> 18   lines.append(line)
     19 return lines
     20 def loadDatasetFinal(filename, split, trainingSet = [], testSet = []):

NameError: name 'lines' is not defined
```

Below is the program code:

```
#kNN implementation in Python 3
import csv
import random
import math
import operator
import urllib.request

# Old Way Commented - Out### FUNCTION GET LINES: Get the files, either directly online or by saving it locally:
def getLines(filename):
  lines = []
#if (filename.startswith(('http', 'ftp', 'sftp'))): #Skip downloading it and open directly online:
 # response = urllib.request.urlopen(filename)
#lines = csv.reader(response.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines())
#else :#TutorialsPoint IDE requires 'r', not 'rb'
with open(r'C:\Users\Radha\Desktop\iris.data.csv','r') as csvfile: #csvreader is an object that is essentially a list of lists
 csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
 for line in csvreader:
  lines.append(line)
return lines
```

Comment: You haven't defined `lines`, before you try to `append` something to it..
The place you are talking about is inside a function `getLines()`, which will get executed when you call it, and not otherwise.

Comment: What's up with this indentation? This won't run

Comment: And ya that too, which @DavyM mentioned :)

Comment: Yep, that’s what I’m thinking. I think that they need to move withopen and everything within their function definition. It may be an indentation error. They’re trying to return lines which isn’t defined globally. They may be trying to do all of this within the function (or method if this is within a class and the OP didn’t show the whole class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the variable lines is only scoped within the getLines() function here.

```
def getLines(filename):
     lines = []
```

You're trying to reference lines outside of that scope and it doesn't exist outside of it yet.

You'll need to create a separate list called lines in the same scope as the function using it, or the outer scope.

You have it commented out...

```
#lines = csv.reader(response.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines())
```

Uncomment that or otherwise redefine lines in the same scope and you won't get a nameerror for lines anymore.

Comment: Yep, I was also thinking they may want lines within the function, and they just have an indentation error here starting with “withopen”. They could put all of that within the function definition I’m thinking and then call the function. The indentation makes it kind of unclear unfortunately. The OP can clear that up.

Comment: Thanks @Matt_G. I had to work on indentation. The problem is gone now.

Answer (score 3):

Right before your `with open(r'C:\`... line, add `lines = []`.

This should solve your problem. Currently you haven't defined the variable `lines`.

Answer (score 1):

Your lines is defined within the function, but you ask to return the value of lines outside of your function. You would need to return the value just outside of the For loop, but not outside of your function

```
for line in csvreader:
   lines.append(line)
return lines
```

You won’t be able to return lines outside of your function. I would move the entire withopen function and everything within the function definition in which I created the empty list “lines”.